# Is there any way to speed up aws code build with maven?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using aws code build for java maven projects. What I observered, for each build trigger, it is downloading dependencies from maven remote repository instead its local. So It is consuming lots of time. Is there any way to speed it up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to cache Maven dependencies in an S3 bucket, which might be reused for the next builds.

When you create the CodeBuild project, in the `BuildSpec` section, you have to specify the location where the Maven dependencies are downloaded:

[image]

And you also may want to create an S3 bucket and provide it as the cache location in the `Artifacts` section:

[image]

For full description on how to create a Maven pipeline with caching, see the AWS support page: [source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-enable-caching-for-aws-codebuild/)

Comment: Don't forget to add the appripiate IAM policy to your Codebuild Role so it can read/write from your S3 cache bucket.

   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-cache",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-cache",/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}